# C# Streamwriter after Flus or Dispose or Close, use again?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have programmed a C# console application with a StreamWriter:
Now I want to close the StreamWriter to write all elements in filename.txt but I want to use the same StreamWriter again, how can I do it?
Open after Close?

Example:

```
StreamWriter Stream = new StreamWriter(filename,true);

for(;;)
{
//this is a endless loop
Stream.WriteLine("THIS MUST BE WRITE TO MY DEVICE NOW")
//now i must use
Stream.Close();
//or
Stream.Dispose();
//or
Stream.Close();

}
// When it begin again from the top of the loop the StreamWriter   doesn´t    work.
```

Now I want to close the StreamWriter to write all elements in filename.txt but I want to use the same StreamWriter again, how can I do it?
Open after Close?

Comment: Why not just make a new one?

Comment: Its a endless loop i wont creat endles new ones, i hope i can make it easy....

Comment: What exactly do you think would be the problem with creating "endless new ones," provided you're properly disposing of the "old ones"?

Comment: There's no way of changing the filename of the StreamWriter, so unless you want to keep writing to the same file you'll need a new instance anyway.

Comment: I write Stream.Flush(); or Stream.Close(); , or Stream.Dispose();

Comment: And than i cant call the same StreamWriter again

Comment: `Close` calls `Dispose`, so once you `Close` it, it cannot be reused. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's there a another way to Write again with the same StreamWriter?

Comment: Why? There's no point. Just create a new one.

Comment: Why? There is no good reason to do that.

Comment: @Hesoyam, I'm pretty sure you're getting hung up on how to do something you *don't need to do*.  What makes you think it will be a problem to create, use, and close several StreamWriters in succession?

Comment: @Hesoyam is not very clear _at least, fo me_ about why you want reuse the `StreamWriter` please edit your question providing more details; maybe there's a better workaround for solve your requirement.

Comment: It can have than more than 100.000 new ones its a endless loop, and I want to write the string into a txt, if I don't make this c# doesn't write it on the physical device... Createing 100.000 new StreamWriters is the best way? than i need one loop more..

Comment: Are you writing to 100000 files, or are you appending to one file 100000 times?  If the latter, define your `StreamWriter` outside the loop and don't call `Close()` within the loop; call it when the loop is finished.  If you're writing to 100000 files, then yes, create 100000 StreamWriters; just make sure you dispose them immediately when you're done with them (i.e. inside the loop).

Comment: @Hesoyam: Why do you think you need one more loop? Can you edit your question to show your attempted solution *with the loop*, while pointing out what is wrong with it?

Comment: So it seems from your edit that inside your loop you're trying to append to a single file and that you want your changes to be flushed immediately to the file.  Correct?  Have you tried `Flush()`?  That should do it.

Comment: Either don't close the writer in the loop; flush it instead. Or put the creation of the writer in the loop.  Either way is fine, which you choose is up to you. But once you close a writer, you must never touch it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Stream.Flush();
// it works fine
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14663835)

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn Please read carefully. This is not a 'thank you' answer.